# Simplify $\frac{1-(\frac{4}{25})^{21}}{1-\frac{4}{25}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

How do you make the jump from:

$$\frac{1-(\frac{4}{25})^{21}}{1-\frac{4}{25}}$$

To:

$$\frac{25^{21}-4^{21}}{25^{21}-4(25^{20})}$$

Comment: multiply the numerator and denominator by $25^{21}$

Comment: One thing you often want to do is not have fractions in the numerator and denominator. Try to remove these by multiplying the whole fraction by 1=$x/x$ for some $x$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \frac{1-(\frac{4}{25})^{21}}{1-\frac{4}{25}}
= \frac{1-(\frac{4}{25})^{21}}{1-\frac{4}{25}} \frac{25^{21}}{25^{21}}
= \frac{25^{21}-(\frac{4}{25})^{21}25^{21}}{25^{21}-\frac{4}{25}25^{21}}
= \frac{25^{21}-4^{21}}{25^{21}-4 \cdot 25^{20}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Have 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{20}(\frac{4}{25})^k=\frac{1-(\frac{4}{25})^{21}}{1-\frac{4}{25}}=\frac{\frac{1}{25}\cdot(\frac{1}{25})^{20}(25^{21}-4^{21})}{\frac{1}{25}(25-4)}=\frac{25^{21}-4^{21}}{21\cdot25^{20}}$$